# Google App Engine & Polymer | Configuration

Tags: python, google-app-engine, polymer, app.yaml

I'm developing a web application on Google App Engine using Python, I understand how to use basically the app.yaml and manage the different files; now I'd like to upgrade my application and use [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/). The root folder has this configuration:

- /MyApp

  - /assets

    - /css
    - /img
    - /js
  - /bower_components
  - /templates
  - app.yaml
  - bower.json
  - index.yaml
  - main.py

I'm having a problem with the bower_components, inside that folder Bower put all the polymer elements that I need in different folders and file inside them, for example:

- /bower_components

  - /core-menu

    - /core-menu.html
  - /core-scaffold

    - /core-scaffold.html

How have I to configure my app yaml? I've tried in different ways to say at mylocalhost & appengine about this folder but every time I try to run my project, I can't see no changes respect to a simple html file. Sometimes, using FireBug i can see the platform js is taken from GAE but I don't know how to rightly link this elements to works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really anything to configure here. These are all static files, exactly the same as the files you have under /assets: so you should point to them in the same way you do with the assets paths.